# Create a file in docker container (alpine images)

Tags: docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

How can I create a file while building docker image?

Below is the docker file used and I want to create a file say config.txt in /usr/bin location

```
FROM gitlab/gitlab-runner:alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN apk add yarn && yarn install
RUN ng build --prod
ENTRYPOINT ["yarn"]
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["run", "start"]
```

I am specifically working on gitlab-runner image

**Edit:**
I know it's a stupid question because I didn't know anything about bash scripting :), earlier.

Comment: The same way as you would create file in a unix system. `RUN touch /usr/bin/config.txt`

Answer (score 2):

We use the `touch` command. 
When you perform `RUN touch /usr/bin/config.txt` you get the file with default permissions (644). Further, you can modify permissions using the `chmod` command.

Comment: what if I want to give full access to the file (chmod 777)  when I create using touch command?

Comment: possible. but u can restrict any public user to enter and run privileged commands by creating a user (test) and only allowing test-user to perform actions to those files and folders (eg: if you don't want anybody to mess up with the config.txt file or script.py)

Comment: how can i create a file in drwx------ location ?

Comment: RUN mkdir -p ${my_location}
RUN touch ${my_location}/config.txt
RUN chmod 700 ${my_location}